# Memcached concurrency w/ lighttpd php

Tags: php, concurrency, memcached, lighttpd

I'm having an issue with memcached. Not sure if it's memcached, php, or tcp sockets but everytime I try a benchmark with 50 or more concurrency to a page with memcached, some of those request failed using apache ab. I get the (99) Cannot assign requested address error.

When I do a concurrency test of 5000 to a regular phpinfo() page. Everything is fine. No failed requests.

It seems like memcached cannot support high concurrency or am I missing something? I'm running memcached with the -c 5000 flag.

---

Server: (2) Quad Core Xeon 2.5Ghz, 64GB ram, 4TB Raid 10, 64bit OpenSUSE 11.1

Comment: How much data are you trying to pump through memcache? 1 byte? 1k? 1 meg? Setting large keys takes time.

Answer (score 5):

### Ok, I've figured it out. Maybe this will help others who have the same problem.

It seems like the issue can be a combination of things.

1. Set the sever.max-worker in the lighttpd.conf to a higher number
   Original: 16   Now: 32
2. Turned off keep-alive in lighttpd.conf, it was keeping the connections opened for too long.
   server.max-keep-alive-requests = 0
3. Change ulimit -n open files to a higher number.
   ulimit -n 65535
4. If you're on linux use:
   server.event-handler = "linux-sysepoll"
   server.network-backend = "linux-sendfile"
5. Increase max-fds
   server.max-fds = 2048
6. Lower the tcp TIME_WAIT before recycling, this keep close the connection faster.
   In /etc/sysctl.conf add:
   net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
   net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 3

   Make sure you force it to reload with: /sbin/sysctl -p

---

After I've made the changes, my server is now running 30,000 concurrent connections and 1,000,000 simultaneous requests without any issue, failed requests, or write errors with apache ab.

### Command used to benchmark: ab -n 1000000 -c 30000 http://localhost/test.php

My Apache can't get even close to this benchmark. Lighttd make me laugh at Apache now. Apache crawl at around 200 concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using just a 4 byte integer, using it as a page counter for testing purposes. Other php pages works fine even with 5,000 concurrent connections and 100,000 requests. This server have alot of horsepower and ram, so I know that's not the issue.

The page that seems to die have nothing but 5 lines to code to test the page counter using memcached. Making the connection gives me this error: (99) Cannot assign requested address.

- This problem start to arise starting with 50 concurrent connections.
- I'm running memcached with -c 5000 for 5000 concurrency.
- Everything is on one machine (localhost)
- The only process running is SSH, Lighttpd, PHP, and Memcached
- There are no users connected to this box (test machine)
- Linux -nofile is set to 32000

---

That's all I have for now, I'll post more information as I found more. It seems like there are alot of people with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested something similar with a file;

```
$mc = memcache_connect('localhost', 11211);
$visitors = memcache_get($mc, 'visitors') + 1;
memcache_set($mc, 'visitors', $visitors, 0, 30);
echo $visitors;
```

running on a tiny virtual machine with nginx, php-fastcgi, and memcached.

I ran `ab -c 250 -t 60 http://testserver/memcache.php` from my laptop in the same network without seeing any errors.

Where are you seeing the error? In your php error log?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for Nginx/php-fpm adding this lines in /etc/sysctl.conf @ Rackspace dedicate servers with Memcached/Couchbase/Puppet:

> # Memcached fix
>   net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
>   net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
>   net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 3

I hope it helps.